# Fetching string in NSURL from a variable

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Right now, I've just some code which fetches the picture from the URL directly.

`ViewController.h`

```
(...)
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
(...)
```

`ViewController.m:`

```
#import Header.h
(...)
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.visitingdc.com/images/eiffel-tower-picture.jpg"];

    NSData *myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData];


}
```

My goal is to view a picture in a imageView which link is stored in a database. The JSON will send the data from the database as a string:

```
[
    {
        "image":"http://www.visitingdc.com/images/eiffel-tower-picture.jpg"
    }
]
```

which will be stored in the variable `*image` in `Header`.

`Header.h`

```
@interface Header : NSObject {

    NSString *image;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *image;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

+ (NSArray *)findAllRemote;

@end
```

What do I have to write in the `NSURL`-code in `ViewController.m` so it fetches the data from the variable instead of a URL-String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store json response in NSSTring, like

```
self.image = ;//where you have parsed JSON data
```

and then use -

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.image];
```